# How to align data-show-columns and data-search in bootstrap in my page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-table

How can I align data-show-columns and data-search? Here is my code:

```
<table id="table-sample" class="table table-striped  table-hover" 
               data-cache="false"
               data-toggle="table"
               data-show-export="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-search="true"
               data-show-columns="true"
```

Please see  image  of my bootstrap table:

[image: Align data column and searchbox]

Comment: Can you attach some code to replicate what you have so far?

Comment: please provide the HTML, CSS, and any JS you have to pull off the layout in your screenshot. It's best if you put it in the code feature of your post, or replicate the screenshot in a codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Mr. @MichaelCoker is there any way to design and customize this bootstrap table?

Comment: When you inspect element on your search bar what class it produce? and also if you are using libraries please include it in the description

Comment: Hi Mr. @claudios here is the plugins that I used /css/bootstrap.min.css
/css/bootstrap-table.css
/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css
/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
/js/bootstrap-table.min.js
/js/bootstrap.min.js
/js/bootstrap-table.js
/js/bootstrap-table-export.js
/js/tableExport.js

Comment: And this is the class name if I inspect element 'columns columns-right btn-group pull-right'

Comment: Can you add your whole table html just don't include the table body. Thanks

Comment: <table id="table-sample" class="table table-striped  table-hover" 
 data-cache="false"
   data-show-export="true"
 data-pagination="true"
                data-click-to-select="true"
                data-show-columns="true" 
                data-search="true"
                data-export-types="['excel', 'pdf', 'csv', 'print']"
                > 
         </table>

Comment: @Bianca Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question directly with any code sample updates, instead of putting in comments, for visibility purposes.